# how do i open .msg file in outlook from a winform application without opening multiple outlook windows

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook

i need suggestions to help me implement a function to open multiple .msg files in outlook from a winform application without opening multiple outlook windows.

i tried Process.Start but it opened multiple outlook windows which is not the desired behavior that i'm looking at.

the .msg file is hosted on a sharepoint site and i have the direct url to the file.

Comment: do you mean this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32899/Reading-an-Outlook-MSG-File-in-C ?

Comment: nope. i would still like to open a .msg file in outlook BUT without opening multiple outlook windows.

Comment: nope. i would still like to open the .msg file in outlook but without opening multiple outlook windows. by using process.start() i'm able to open multiple .msg but also opening multiple outlook windows at the same time.

Comment: "Open" as in "show it to the user"? Or as in "read various properties from the MSG file"?

Comment: show it to the user. just like the way you double click a .msg file from your desktop

Comment: i added on additional details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> i tried Process.Start but it opened multiple outlook windows which is not the desired behavior that i'm looking at.

Only one instance of Outlook can be run at the same time. What you see when opening multiple .msg files are inspectors windows. I suppose you get the same picture if you try to open files manually.

> show it to the user. just like the way you double click a .msg file from your desktop

Use Process.Start method passing a path to the message file. There is no need to specify the Outlook.exe.

Finally, as a workaround, you may consider downloading items locally and then using the Outlook object model for opening files from the disk. The [CreateItemFromTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff865637.aspx) method of the Application class creates a new Microsoft Outlook item from an Outlook template (.oft) or message file (.msg) and returns the new item. See [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/) for more information.

Comment: for the mailitem.display(), it seems like only 1 .msg can be opened until it is closed by the user, the winform is unresponsive while the .msg file is opened. is that the normal behavior?

Comment: Most probably you pass true to the method. You need to display a non-modal window instead passing false.